# Routing between two OpenVPN tunnels fails

Tags: linux, routing, openvpn

We have three sites A, B an C. There is an OpenVPN link from A to B and from A to C. A is the client for both.

```
Bnet Cnet
|    |
B    C
 \   /
  \ /
   V
   A
   |
   Anet
```

Anet can communicate with Bnet and Cnet just fine.
Both Bnet and Cnet can communicate with Anet.
The problem is that Bnet cannot communicate with Cnet.

The routing on both B and C is configured from the openvpn.conf:

```
route 192.168.108.0 255.255.255.0
route 10.9.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

The result is visible in "route -n". It works for 192.168.108.x (Anet) but not the others.

When I do a "tcpdump -i tun0 proto ICMP" on B and A when pinging C from B, I can see the requests getting into the tunnel but not out of it:

```
17:34:16.216271 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.9.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 40798, seq 1, length 64
```

There are no firewall rules at all, all policies are ACCEPT.

Is there anything preventing packets from one client tunnel to get to another client tunnel ?

Answer (score 1):

The "route" commands above were not enough, there was a

```
client-config-dir client-configs
```

Entry which led to a subconfig file:

```
iroute 192.168.208.0 255.255.255.0
```

I added this:

```
iroute 10.9.0.0 255.255.0.0
```

And now it is routing properly between the VPNs !